# open a local file via path from a website on heroku

Tags: node.js, reactjs, express, heroku, filesystems

Hi I am trying to find a solution for uploading a file from a local computer using path instead of the dialog box of `<input type="file" />`.
Of course it will work when running on localhost using fs library, the issue is when the server is in production and up (in my case heroku) and then the provided path will be looked for within the server (vm on the cloud) instead on the local ccomputer.
Is there any way in the front (React) perhaps to implement something like this ?

Again i want to access local files using the user's provided path to them in his computer while the server is hosted somewhere else.

[as the example here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/W10lZ.png)

this is what I naively tried (worked locally):

```
  app.post("/form", (req, res) => {
    const { value } = req.body;
    fs.createReadStream(path.normalize(value))
      .pipe(csv({}))
      .on("data", (data) => csv_data.push(data))
      .on("end", () => {
        res.send(JSON.stringify(mergeData(csv_data)));
      });
  });
};
```

Comment: provide the code you have tried please.

Comment: I updated the post, basically I used the fs npm package but it works only locally since it's browsing the files in the computer it's running on, so not working on production of course

Comment: is the file an html or something else?

Comment: csv, but i need to find a way to access the user's computer from the server

Comment: if the file is not on the server and you expect the user to upload it you need some frontend code for that.

Comment: I know, there is a dialog box solution with <input type="file" /> but i am trying to find a solution in react to open via route

Comment: That example doesn't look real. _Thankfully_, your code has no way of accessing the user's local filesystem. That would be a security and privacy nightmare. Users will need to use a file input. (You may be able to show the path to the file _after_ the user has used the dialog, but I'm not sure. You will _not_ be able to take a path from a user and load the file at that path from their filesystem.)